# how to 'ls' another directory in unix script?

Tags: shell, unix

My code

```
echo $ls | /var/lib/judgem/records/
```

I'm trying to get the script to show me all the files inside the folder "records"

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean recursively?

Comment: I'd use something like `find "$DIRECTORY" -type f -maxdepth 1` where $DIRECTORY is what you're operating on. Remove the `-maxdepth 1` if you want files in subdirectories as well. Remove the `-type f` if you want subdirectories as well as files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or, if you want to list the contents of another directory without the full path, i.e. as though you were in the other directory, but without ending up there after the command has finished, you can use a subshell like this:

```
(cd /var/lib/judgem/records/ && ls)
```

You will notice you stay in whatever directory you were in but the files are listed without the full path of /var/lib/judgem/records on the front.

Comment: You don't need to `cd`. When you give a directory name argument to `ls`, it lists the contents of the directory. You only get the full path if you do `ls /var/lib/judgem/records/*`.

Comment: works also nicely like that to get all folders from usbstick once mounted
(cd /mnt/usbstick && ls -d */)

Answer (score 18):

Give the directory as the argument to `ls`:

```
ls /var/lib/judgem/records
```

Comment: doesnt work. out is just 
ls /var/lib/mailman/lists/
. same as the person above

Comment: What person above? I don't see how it can output a filename in a completely different directory.

Comment: @Barmar could you please tell how to run this command `ls -d -1 $PWD/*.*` on a given location.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why doesn't that work? What do you mean by "on a given location"? `$PWD` specifies the current directory. If you want some other directory, put that in place of `$PWD`.

Answer (score 1):

To ls on another dir, you need specify the absolute / relative path accordingly..

pwd => /usr/local
ls /home/fe567/data

or

pwd => /home/fe567
ls ./data

Answer (score -1):

`find /var/lib/judgem/records/ -type f -maxdepth 1`

Comment: Unless you add `-maxdepth `1, your command will list all files in the entire _subtree_ of `/var/lib/judgem/records/`, not just the files located _directly_ in `/var/lib/judgem/records/`.

Answer (score -2):

to ls another directory provide the directory after the command.
should look something like this:

```
ls /var/lib/judgem/records
```

this is bash btw.

Comment: Since when do you use `\` as the directory separator in Bash?!

Comment: You mean `ls /var/lib/judgem/records`

Comment: You are correct Keith. use /, I sent from my phone while waiting for lunch lol didnt notice.

Comment: There's nothing `bash`-specific about this command: `ls` is an executable (as opposed to a shell builtin) and `/var/lib/judgem/records` is a string literal (even though it is unquoted, given its value, neither `bash` nor any other shell that I know of would perform any expansion on it).